# Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement'

Tags: angular, typescript

When I try to assign my file blob to a File object it gives me the following error:

> core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidStateError:
>   Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input
>   element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to
>   the empty string. Error: Failed to set the 'value' property on
>   'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may
>   only be programmatically set to the empty string.

I checked the content when I `console.log()` into it it does give me the content of the file. Why is it giving me the error when I try to assign it to `examen_bestand`?

HTML:

```
<input type="file" [(ngModel)]="examen_bestand" name="examen_bestand" class="form-control-file" id="exampleInputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp" (change)="fileChanged($event)">
```

TS:

```
export class StudentUploadComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() examensStudent: Examen[] = [];
  examen_id: number;
  examen_bestand: any;

  constructor(private serv: ExamService) { }

  onSubmit(form) {
    console.log(form.values);
  }

  fileChanged(e) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      this.examen_bestand = reader.result;
    };
    reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serv.getExams().subscribe(data => this.examensStudent = data);
  }

}
```

Comment: Does the error occur while inputting the file or on component load.?

Comment: It occurs when I select the file. So in the "fileChanged()" function. To be more exact I'm pretty sure it's the line `this.examen_bestand = reader.result;`

Comment: You're setting the file input to the result of the file contents you've selected. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with [(ngModel)], but you're right. It happens when you set examen_bestand to the file contents.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the blob so I can save it to the database.

Comment: Oh, well you don't need ngModel for that.

Comment: Ah very stupid of me that was indeed the problem.. I forgot I am retrieving the data through the (change) anyway. Do you mind posting that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Here you are trying to bind the input field through [(ngModel)] to the blob which is causing the issue. Was that intentional or was it a typo.? I guess input type=file doesnt take blob as the value.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remove ngModel. Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhgm9w) you likely don't need at this point. :)

Comment: your stackblitz is empty and have no implementation

Comment: I guess stackblitz has done some cleanup in the last two and a half years. My appologies.

Comment: There is no solution in your link attched

Comment: the stackblitz is empty

Answer (score 31):

I was getting this error, and just got it resolved. At least for me it was because on my input I had a 'value' in the input field set to this.state.image like this:

```
          <label htmlFor='image'>
                    Image
                    <input 
                        type='file' 
                        id='file' 
                        name="file"
                        placeholder="Upload an Image" 
                        required 
                        value={this.state.image}
                        onChange={this.uploadFile}
                        />
                </label>
```

After I removed the line of 
value={this.state.image}

it started working.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Same here. Do you what is causing it?

Comment: I had a similar problem in React and this solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In case you could not get access to @wolghoundjesse stackblitz, you have to remove the `[(ngModel)]="examen_bestand"` from the `input` and get the file name from the `fileChanged($event)` in the TS:

```
fileChanged(file){
     this.examen_bestand = file.target.files[0].name;
     ... 
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6074#issuecomment-347187761

Answer (score 0):

Once I removed the value attribute on my input, the error was gone